# cz ccTLD domain regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex `/^([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])*){1,60}\.cz$/i`.

Rules:

1. Domain Name may contain only characters [a-z,0-9,-]
2. The maximum Domain Name Length is not more than 63 characters
3. A Domain Name must not begin or end with “-“ character
4. A Domain Name must not contain two characters “-“ in sequence

And I need complete this regex with last rule (javascript).

Comment: Are you sure that 63 length limit is not for part before `.cz`? Then it would be total length limit of 66. I also believe Czech domain name cannot be as short as one character before `.cz`, so you should add a minumum length limit as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex `/^(?!.{64})[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*\.cz$/i`

Comment: @PatrikVotoček - to set a minimum limit as well (to not allow one letter .cz domain names), add `(?=.{5})` behind `^`.

Answer (score 2):

> A Domain Name must not contain two characters “-“ in sequence

A simple way would just be to add a [negative lookahead condition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like `(?!.*--)` in your expression after the `^`.

Comment: Qtax, I would expect much better answer from you, as ususally you are the best in regex.

Comment: @Ωmega thanks, but you already had the answer like one I wanted to suggest, so no need. :-) I was planning to deleting this one, but then someone voted, so must have been useful in some way.